# About using View widget

Tags: android, canvas, android-widget

I want to define, in the XML layout file, a placeholder for a `Canvas` to draw text in it that can be panned, zoomed, rotated, etc.
Is the correct way for this to define a `View` widget?

```
<View
    android:id="..."
    ....>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not really optimal.
You can try:

1. Create a customized View hat can be panned, zoomed, rotated (extends View) and define it in the layout. For example

   ```
   <com.example.CustomView
    android:id="..."
     ....>
   </com.example.CustomView>
   ```
2. Or define a layout for a holder and add your view to that holder later.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/holder"
      ....
   />
   ```

Hope this help.

Comment: What does the custom view gives me that I cannot do with the View's canvas? Specifically I only need to display text and catch pinch gestures for zooming, panning and rotating. Are you saying it can't be done with just a `View`, please explain.